# MATLAB File I/O

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io

I am trying to read in a .txt file that is a matrix and turn it into a row vector. However, I keep getting the error "Empty format string is not supported at the end of a file." Here is my code. Can anyone explain why I'm getting this?

```
filename = 'matrix.txt';
fID = fopen(filename);
M = csvread(filename);
rowVector = M(:);
```

Comment: What is inside your .txt file?

Comment: Does your data file have a header line?  If so remove that?  Is there a blank line at the end of your file?

Comment: the text file is a matrix of number separated by commas. There is no header. There might be a blank at the end. Would that be a problem and how would I fix it?

Comment: If there is a blank line at the end of the file, you would have to open your data file and delete the blank line, save your data file, and try again.

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but, you don't need to fopen the file before calling csvread.

Comment: You might also consider trying to use the importdata function to see if you get different results from that.

Comment: @WilliamDiuguid try running the example from [the documentation for `tline`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html). If this method makes it through your whole file it can be adapted to read your data.